# FastAPI Post Request Not Working, Response variable throwing exception

Tags: javascript, python, async-await, fastapi

I have this problem where after initializing the response variable, it is immediately throwing an exception, this is the error it gives me:

> app.js:36 Error:
> processImages @ app.js:36
> await in processImages (async)
> onclick @ Demo/:13

I've already checked the webapi by debugging and its working fine. It gives an ok.

app.js file:

```
async function processImages() {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    const outputImagesDiv = document.getElementById('outputImages');

    const files = fileInput.files;
    if (files.length === 0) {
        alert('Please select at least one image.');
        return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const file of files) {
        formData.append('files', file);
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3003/process_images', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });//throws exception directly after this

        if (response.status !== 200) {
            alert('Error processing images.');
            return;
        }

        const result = response.data;
        outputImagesDiv.innerHTML = '';

        for (let i = 0; i < result.imagesWithLandmarks.length; i++) {
            const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
            imgElement.src = `data:image/png;base64,${result.imagesWithLandmarks[i]}`;
            outputImagesDiv.appendChild(imgElement);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        alert('An error occurred while processing images.');
    }
}
```

main.py(web api)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from typing import List
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from DlibActuator import DlibActuator

app = FastAPI()
dlib = DlibActuator()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.post("/process_images")
async def process_images(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    image_paths = []
    for file in files:
        with open(f"./uploads/{file.filename}", "wb") as buffer:
            buffer.write(file.file.read())
        image_paths.append(f"./uploads/{file.filename}")

    result = dlib.process_images(image_paths)

    return result.dict()

@app.get("/check_api")
def check_api():
    return {"status": "API is working correctly"}
```

Im guessing the problem is with how I am receiving the response? Again it throws an exception upon initializing the response variable and the web api is working fine

Here is what the terminal from the server side telling me:

> 127.0.0.1:63405 - "POST /process_images HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

EDIT: Upon further inspection, it seems to be throwing the exception BEFORE the API is done executing the function and returning a result!

EDIT2: If I replace the web api function with it returning a simple json string, the web api works fine! I'm assuming whats going wrong is that the fetch is throwing an exception since it thinks the web api is taking too long (which it does since it's using a custom data model I've trained). I tried giving it a timeout but alas. Any suggestions?

Comment: json dictionaries don't allow a comma after the last element.  Try removing the comma after `body: formData,`

Comment: Are you getting any error in your backend logs? And is that really the full js traceback? It looks truncated.

Comment: I've edited the error to make it more easy to look at, but yeah that's all im getting from the error varaible.

Also i removed the "," from formData still got the same problem

Here is the response I am getting in the terminal running the api: 127.0.0.1:63405 - "POST /process_images HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

I checked the contents of results, its fine.